# javascript code to hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to write javascript code where there is an object called "costCenter" which the visibility should be false. but when i click on the "computer" item on my dropdownlist it will set the "costcenter" visibility to true.

so far this is what i have. is this the proper use of syntax for javascript?

```
function hideMe()
{
var g = document.getElementById('costcenterid');
var e = document.getElementById('dg_form_ctl02_DropDownList1');
if(e == 'computer')
{
g.style.display = 'block';
else
g.style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

C# code behind

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"hwa","hideMe();",true);
```

i found this code from somewhere, but i'm not sure what goes in the "hwa"

Comment: assuming `SetVisible` is valid, this looks like it should work

Comment: What do you mean by an object 'costCenter'? Is that an HTML element or something?

Comment: Okay, if i wanted to call this method with c# code how would it look like?

Comment: actually, check the answer I'm about to post

Comment: @hsalama the object 'costCenter' i think would be an html element. its part of a gridview row and the datasource is connected to sqlserver

Comment: @user1596075 do you already have a method named SetVisible that takes a true/false param?

Comment: @hsalama no i do not, can you show me some code to be able to do that? I thought it was already a class provided.. thanks.

Comment: @user1596075, use Miguel's idea then. "none" in the quotes hides the element, "block" re-shows it

Comment: I have updated the code, does that look like it's correct?

Comment: actually i tried running the code with another id in replacement of the costcenter, and it didn't do anything. didn't hide it.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display="none|block"
```

Comment: is there anything i need to put inside the "none|block"?

Answer (score 0):

rather than `.value`, try this:

```
var selectedVar = document.getElementById("dg_form_ctl02_DropDownList1").options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

As far as calling it from c# code, that depends on what kind of project this is. If it's winforms, do it from the codebehind. If it's mvc, I'd generally suggest not doing it at all.

Comment: hmm it is a website kind of project, but i had to use some code  behind, okay. thanks.